# Does not calling Future.get cause any issue?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, future, callable

I am executing a certain flow wherein I submit some task to Callable and store the output in `Future<> future`. 
In some of the cases I am not calling `future.get()` to retrieve the value nor am I cancelling the task. Can this cause any issue?

Comment: No issue in that, except that you won't know when the task fails.

Comment: You won't know if the task failed or what the outcome of the task was.

Comment: Case where I am not getting the future value I don't need to know the execution status of the task...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am executing a certain flow wherein I submit some task to `Callable` and store the output in `Future<>` future. In some of the cases I am not calling `future.get()` to retrieve the value nor am I cancelling the task. Can this cause any issue?

No it won't cause any issues.  The `future` will be garbage collected as long as no one is holding a reference to it.

Obviously you could submit a `Runnable` instead of the `Callable` if you don't need the results from the `call()` method but it sounds to me like you want to programatically  chose to just forget about the `Callable` which is fine.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases, when you do not care the execution result of this task, it will not cause any issue.

But please notice this  special function of [`future.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get()):

> Memory consistency effects: Actions taken by the asynchronous
>   computation happen-before actions following the corresponding
>   Future.get() in another thread.

Here is an example:

```
int i = 0;
```

and if you let

```
i = 1;
```

in the task, then read `i` after `future.get`, it can gurantees you get the fresh value `1`.

Without calling `future.get`, you might get the obsolete value `0`.